Using ar in unity for indoor navigation
I'm using unity AR( Augmented Reality) to create various things such as dropdown and rest for navigation I've even created 3d model of map but unable to do navigation , I've also done QR code and 3d map just don't know any free and open source to do direction precise such as meters left to turn , if there's any way to do this please let me know.
I've made and tried 2d map and 3d modelling and navigation shortest path
I'm unable to create a path showing from one point to another using camera if anyone knows any free source not( map box and openstreetmap either)
thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
